# Split HTML table into multiple tables based on its columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to create a responsive HTML/CSS table. On the mobile screen, this table should break into 2 tables based on its columns. Here is my original table:

```
                <table class="table" style="position: relative; left: 0%; display: inline-block;">
                    <thead style="color:#ceb03d">
                        <tr>
                            <th id="mainItem"></th>
                            <th id="column_1">column1</th>
                            <th id="column_2">column2</th>
                            <th id="column_3">column3</th>
                            <th id="column_4">column4</th>
                            <th id="column_5">column5</th>
                            <th id="column_6">column6</th>
                            <th id="column_7">column7</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in model.items"> //The table contains several rows.
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

On mobile, I want to show the first table by these columns:
"mainItem", "column_1", "column_2", "column_3", "column_4"
The second table (which is below the first table) should contain these columns:
"mainItem", "column_1", "column_5", "column_6", "column_7"

How can I use css media to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.desktop-container {
  display: block;
}
.mobile-container {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .desktop-container {
     display: none;
   }
  .mobile-container {
     display: block;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-container">
  place desktop table here
</div>
<div class="mobile-container">
  place mobile table here
</div>
```

The above is only a simple example. They don't have to be `<div>` containers, you can do this on `<tr>` elements, if you want, but you'll need to use `display: table-row` instead of `display: block` if you place the classes on `<tr>`s.  Use whatever value you want to give to that element's `display` when it is visible.

---

`@media` queries are really simple to use:

```
any-selector {
  any-css-rule
}
@media(any-condition) {
  any-selector {
    /* same selector as above */
    any-css-rule 
    /* same rule as above, different value */
  }
}
```

When `any-condition` is true, what is inside `@media` applies. When it is not true, what is above it applies. That's all.